# Suggestions for technology for web service with both web and mobile clients

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, web-services, jakarta-ee, lamp

I have set up a LAMP server on aws. I am planning to create a web service with both a web client and an android client. I am not exactly sure where to start. I would like to create a RESTful service but have no experience with it and don't know where to start. I have hit restful services for the android app that I have created but have not designed one myself.
I have worked with Java and RoR. I would like to learn Python as well if required. 
Any suggestions would be great.

question in short: **What technology to use for a web service with both a mobile client and a web based client?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the user interface using **HTML** and then get the data asynchronous (eg: **AJAX**) using **JavaScript** from the server.

This has the advantage that both the desktop and the mobile client can eventually be the same, while the server can completely ignore the user-interface mechanics and focus on the services you are providing.

If you want to make the mobile client "Native" (eg: android app), then you merely make it "talk" with the server using HTML asynchronous requests.

Edit:
On the server side you can do something like this:

```
// extract uri from request
$request = explode("?", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$uri = explode("/", $request[0]);

// sanitize user input
foreach($_POST as $k => &$v) $v = addslashes($v);

// prepare file input
foreach($_FILES as $k => $v)
{
  if (empty($k) or empty($v)) unset($_FILES[$k]);
}
```

This give you the request details, then client-side you do requests like:

```
site.com?php_service/param1/param2/...
```

Comment: I particularly need to know what to use in the back end, the data model and database connection part.

Comment: There is no standard way of doing it at the server side, you just roll your own...
You basically get an html request on the php side, elaborate it based on the request details and return ajax data.
Then on the client-side you only make ajax requests, take the response data and show it to the user.

Comment: I have also heard of Java restlet (I am not exactly sure about the technicalities but I am guessing it does work in a similar fashion), comparing this with PHP/RoR which do you think would be better?

Comment: @viper You do the client-side REST-fu in Javascript anyway, so it can even be better to use some dedicated solutions like a java servlet on the server-side (but it is surely not simpler).